# Notification in a JavaFX app

Tags: java, javafx, controlsfx

I would like to add a notification to some actions in my JavaFX application. Such as a successful connection to a server, a disconnection to a server, etc ...
I tried the NotificationPane from ControlsFX but I can't hide the bar after a short time delay. It seems that you can only hide it after an user interaction.

If you know another library who does something similar or even better, I'm looking forward to it.

Plus I would like to make my notifications look like that :[image: IE Notification]

so it doesn't take the whole width of the application :)

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

`NotificationPane` has a [`hide()`](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/NotificationPane.html#hide--) method that you can call directly, after whatever delay you need. So you can just do

```
NotificationPane notificationPane = ... ;

// show for 1 second:
notificationPane.show();
PauseTransition delay = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(1));
delay.setOnFinished(e -> notificationPane.hide());
delay.play();
```

You can probably achieve the layout you need by adding padding to the notification pane (though I haven't tested this):

```
notificationPane.setPadding(new Insets(0, 30, 0, 30));
```

Comment: Thanks ! it works fine for the delay. But changing the padding doesn't work because the NotificationPane contains my BorderPane so the whole thing is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use if you want the [TrayIcon.displayMessage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html#displayMessage(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.awt.TrayIcon.MessageType)). But you cant realy style this Messages.

Otherwise you can implement this yourself.

doesn't sounds that complicated.

Just create a new Stage and show it with your Message then after a delay hide the Stage and your done.