# show notification on desktop when new message received by an java application

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I develop a desktop chat application using java swing. 
in this application i open the chat page in webview, and i am able to send and receive message.

I want to add a functionality in my application that if someone text me, i get a notification on my desktop like "new message received".

how can i do that? 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Run a separate thread observing for incoming messages, if any message is received show a pop up in system tray or a dialog, as you prefer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notification in a JavaFX app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35319671/notification-in-a-javafx-app)

Answer (score 2):

You can use javaFX library [ControlsFx](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/) to generate Notifications. Like this one

```
Notifications notify = Notifications.create().title("Message Alert")
                        .text("New Message arrived tap to view")
                        .hideAfter(javafx.util.Duration.seconds(2))
                        .position(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
                notify.darkStyle();
notify.showInformation();
```